# Receiving encrypted JSON response after successful POST request in SoapUI

Tags: json, rest, http-post, soapui, postman

I am trying to test a POST request in SoapUI 5.0 with JSON as the format.

It works fine if I use Postman, but if I try to accomplish the same within SoapUI I just get a junk JSON response which seems to be not encoded properly.
According to the response headers everything must be OK (200 OK status, correct content-length), it just doesn't display correctly.

I found out that it has to do with the encoding, so I tried to set `Content-Type: application/json, charset=UTF-8` in the request headers and also to set the "Encoding" property in the request properties to "UTF-8".

Still the same junk response.

Any ideas?

[image: Raw Request & Raw Response]

Answer (score 2):

Your response is in `gzip` format, see the `Content-Encoding:gzip` http header in your response.

Theoretically SOAPUI must ungzip this automatically for you and show the response in a plain text, however seems that doesn't work for your case. I try with some REST API with a response gzip encoded an the response is decoded correctly. (I'm using SOAPUI 5.2.1 instead of 5.0.0 as you do).

Then a possible workaround could be to change your current http-header `accept-encoding : gzip` value to `accept-encoding : identity` to tell explicitly to the server that you want the response in plain text.

If `identity` doesn't work for this WS, try telling that `gzip` is unacceptable with a `q` value of `0`: `Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0` or with: `Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=0, identity; q=1.0`

If as you comment this not works for you, probably due your WS is ignoring this headers, you can try to ungzip the response yourself using a Groovy script test step with the following workaround:

1. Configure the `Dump File` property in your REST TestRequest Properties:

[image]

2. Create a Groovy testStep an use the follow script to ungzip the dump response in order to get it as plain text:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream

def buffer = new byte[1024]

// create the zip input stream from your dump file
def dumpFilePath = 'C:/temp/'
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("${dumpFilePath}/dumpRest.json")
// create the instance to ungzip
def gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis)
// fileOutputStream for the result
def fos = new FileOutputStream("${dumpFilePath}/dumpRestUngizped.json")
// decompress content
gzis.eachByte(1024){ buf, len -> fos.write(buf,0,len)}
// close streams
gzis.close()
fos.close()
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not working, still the same output.

Edit:
It actually completely ignores the statement. It still says `Content-Encoding:gzip` in the response header.

Comment: @tugadesperado I update my answer, trying to do the same with a different value for the http header, hope this time it's more helpful :)

Comment: I tried both of your examples and it gives me still the exact same raw response...

These are the headers:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Content-Type: application/json`

`Content-Length: 502`

`Connection: Keep-Alive`

`MessageType: Application`

`Content-Encoding: gzip`